# MySQL - multiple join relation and count rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count, join

I want to build SQL query with good performance approach. I need to select all categories and count bands associated with this categories.

Structure:

bands:

```
 id       | band_name      |cat_id
----------|----------------|------------
 1        | Business 1     | 1  
 2        | Business 12    | 2
 3        | Business 123   | 2
```

categories:

```
id        | name           
----------|----------------
 1        | Business 1     
 2        | Business 12    
 3        | Business 123
```

connections:

```
id        | band_id        |cat_id
----------|----------------|------------
 1        | 1              | 1  
 2        | 2              | 1
 3        | 2              | 1
```

Query:

```
SELECT c.name AS category_name, (SELECT COUNT(icc.band_id) FROM cms_bands_categories_connections AS icc RIGHT JOIN cms_bands AS ib ON icc.band_id = ib.id) AS bands_sum FROM 
                    cms_bands_categories AS c 
                 JOIN cms_bands_categories_connections AS cc ON 
                    c.id = cc.category_id 
                GROUP BY
                    c.id
```

Results are very strange - bands_sum is evual to 3 in each row. Don't blame my structure - I had to modyfi it becouse of requirements specification change.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a subquery instead of just an aggregation?

```
SELECT c.name AS category_name, COUNT(cc.band_id) AS bands_sum
FROM cms_bands_categories c JOIN
     cms_bands_categories_connections cc
     ON c.id = cc.category_id 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

You don't even need the `bands` table to count them.  That information is in the connections table.